# How can I force an application to load .NET classes from a different assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, class, redirect

Does anyone know of any way to force an application to load a specific .NET class from a separate file, without having that application's source code? Like, say, if I want to make a change to a single class in mscorlib and see what happens in a certain application, I wouldn't want to have to make a wrapper DLL for *every single class* in mscorlib. One thing that brought this to mind is because I absolutely **hate** the Windows folder browser dialog, and I'd like to be able to write a replacement class for FolderBrowserDialog. Then whenever an application tries to use it it'll use mine instead.

I just found `TypeForwardedToAttribute`, but that requires access to source code. I'd like to be able to do this to an existing application I don't have any source code for.

Answer (score 1):

[Assembly redirection / publisher policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx) is for this purpose but it's not very likely that you can apply it to mscorlib, especially in a system-wide fashion. When assembly redirection is used, one can redirect a given assembly to a different version of the same assembly but the target assembly must have the same public key token as the original one. Since mscorlib is strongly named (in the GAC) it's not likely that you can re-sign it after your modifications.

Also, keep in mind that `FolderBrowserDialog` internally uses `SHBrowseForFolder` so if you somehow manage to redirect it or redirect mscorlib, you still only handled managed applications - any native applications will still use the underlying `SHBrowseForFolder` call and you'll end up seeing different folder dialogs in different applications.

Additionally (after reading your comment) your users may already be familiar with the 'regular' `Browse for folder` dialog - giving them a different one may end up confusing some of them if you do that. I'm not saying it's a great dialog (it's not) but standard behavior across all applications is better for users than a single application with a better dialog.

Why not create a new folder browser dialog instead in your own projects? It's not that hard to do so. Here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/159352/FolderBrowserDialogEx-A-C-customization-of-FolderB) to start with - it has links to other articles that describe techniques to change the dialog (but only within a single application).

Comment: Well obviously I'm not going to use `FolderBrowserDialog` in my own applications; I respect my users more than that. ;-) That was just an example anyway. However, I'm not talking about software I write; I'm talking about modifying the behavior of existing applications without having access to its source code.

Comment: @flarn2006 I edited my answer regarding `SHBrowseForFolder` which is the underlying API used by the .NET wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible using .Net policy settings. Check [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0-201-73411-7/ch02lev1sec5#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTAtMjAxLTczNDExLTcvMjE=) out (extracted from Don Box's excellent ***Essential .Net***).  Look especially at Listing 2.4 and Figure 2.11.  The only thing is  I am not sure if you can override built-in .Net classes and assemblies using this technique.

Listing 2.4. Setting the Version Policy

Version policy can be specified at three levels: per application, per component, and per machine. Each of these levels gets an opportunity to process the version number, with the results of one level acting as input to the level below it. This is illustrated in Figure 2.11. Note that if both the application's and the machine's configuration files have a version policy for a given assembly, the application's policy is run first, and the resultant version number is then run through the machine-wide policy to get the actual version number used to locate the assembly. In this example, if the machine-wide configuration file redirected version 1.3.0.0 of Acme.HealthCare to version 2.0.0.0, the assembly resolver would use version 2.0.0.0 when version 1.2.3.4 was requested because the application's version policy maps version 1.2.3.4 to 1.3.0.0.

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about class-level redirection. Doesn't what you're referring to only work for entire assemblies at a time? I would still want it to use that assembly normally, with the exception of one or two classes, which I would want loaded from somewhere else.

Comment: yes, but if you write a substitute assembly that redirects to the built-in assembly for every class except the one you want to override the behavior of ...  I'm not saying this would be smart, in fact it would probably be very unsmart in many ways, but you are asking if it's possible ...

Comment: Yeah but it'd still be a real pain to have to put in a stub for every single class and every single method, especially with updates. Is there some kind of tool that can break apart assemblies into something kind of like a jar file, so I can replace individual classes and pack it together?

Answer (score 0):

You can always try decompiling the dll with [ILSpy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharpdevelop/files/ILSpy/2.0/ILSpy_Master_2.1.0.1603_RTW_Binaries.zip/download). It allows you spit out a project file with generated source code from any .net dll.

You can then edit the generated source code and compile a modified dll.

Comment: Good idea, but decompilations aren't always perfect, and I'd rather not have to deal with an imperfect decompilation for a whole bunch of classes if I only want to change a few.

Comment: You can simply output the classes you need. You don't necessarily have to output code for the whole dll. Simply take the code you need and it should be fine (there will be some code in a class you won't need to include). I've had to do plenty of decompilation in order to implement features that other platforms don't have in their SDK and I haven't encountered any issues.

Comment: But then how would I get it to use the original DLL for the classes that I didn't replace?

Comment: Realistically, you would actually decompile and output the source code for the app you want to change and open up the generated project file. You would then add the new classes to the project, and simply use your new classes rather than the mscorlib classes. You would then be able to compile and run the modified app.